# GO routine never exits based on stop condition - unable to find the reason

Tags: go

In this example, we have a worker. The idea here is simulate `clean shutdown` of all go routines based on a condition.

In this case, go routines get spun - based on workers count. Each go routine reads the channel, does some work and sends output to the `outputChannel`.

The main go routine reads this output and prints it. To simulate a stop condition, the `doneChannel` is closed. Expected outcome is that `select` inside each go routine will pick this up and execute `return` which in turn will call the `defer println`. The actual output is that it never gets called and main exits.

Not sure what's the reason behind this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

const jobs = 100
const workers = 1

var timeout = time.After(5 * time.Second)

func main() {

    doneChannel := make(chan interface{})
    outputChannel := make(chan int)

    numberStream := generator()

    for i := 1; i <= workers; i++ {
        go worker(doneChannel, numberStream, outputChannel)
    }

    // listen for output
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case i := <-outputChannel:
            log.Println(i)
        case <-timeout:
            // before you timeout cleanup go routines
            break loop
        }
    }

    close(doneChannel)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Println("main exited")

}

func generator() <-chan int {
    defer log.Println("generator completed !")
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= jobs; i++ {
            c <- i
        }

        defer close(c)
    }()
    return c
}

func worker(done <-chan interface{}, c <-chan int, output chan<- int) {
    // this will be a go routine
    // Do some work and send results to output Channel.
    // Incase if the done channel is called kill the go routine.

    defer log.Println("go routines exited")

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            log.Println("here")
            return
        case i := <-c:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // worker delay
            output <- i * 100

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `main` never *waits for* the other goroutines to complete. It closes `doneChannel`, logs a message, and returns. When `main` returns, all other goroutines are destroyed, so if you want other goroutines to finish first, you must wait for them at this point. How you implement that wait is up to you, though `sync.WaitGroup` is commonly chosen.

Answer (score 0):

When your main loop finishes during the timeout, you continue your program and

1. Close done channel
2. Print message
3. Exit

There is no reason to wait for any goroutine to process the signal of this channel.

If you add a small sleep you will see some messages

In real scenarios we use a waitgroup to be sure all goroutine finish properly

Comment: Thanks for reply. Adding a timeout results in same behavior. Can we not signal using channels ?.  In this case we don't want to use wait groups and we are planning to use channels in this use case.

Comment: Channels are ok. You can use context with timeout / cancel if you want (still need for / select)

Comment: Also, since you are closing the numStream (will be nice keep the same name everywhere) after finish to add all numbers, your workers must detect it and stop too. `case i, ok := <- c:` will detect the closing of c if ok is false (or true, never remember- try to print it)

Comment: The question is more related to - why the defer println is not executing even after giving sufficient time for the go routines to finish execution and respond to done.

Comment: Probably all your goroutines are stuck trying to write on a unbuffered channel. Add some buffer value and check again

Comment: Another way is add a second select to write into output channel and listen to done channel too

Comment: The scenario that you describe is a pipeline of one source, one or more “workers” and a single output. I will focus on close the source and it automatically close the workers (consuming the channel in a single for loop) and using waitgroup to wait for all “workers”. Once all workers are done, we can safely close the output channel. If you read the output as for loop, will be natural the ending of this pipeline

Comment: Like this https://go.dev/play/

Comment: Finally got the ``correct`` answer at https://faun.pub/implmenting-timeout-in-golang-ee2bc4aa6ae4.  The problem here is that we stop listening to ``outputChannel`` when we timeout. Therefore any go routine which is trying to send will block. Hence the solution is to buffer the ``outputChannel``.  The idea of having a ``double select`` can still lead to the same original problem.

Comment: Example at https://go.dev/play/p/qEM4xvWT5Zr